# How to find the exact weekday of last year for a date in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

I want to find the weekdate for the last year like today in javascript?

Today is Monday, 18 May 2015
Last year was Sunday, 18 May 2015

So I want to get the nearest Monday of last year, e.g. in this case Monday, 18.05.2014.

How to calculate it?

Comment: How do you define _nearest_? Maybe week numbers are relevant?

Comment: I think your question is wrong... Today is Monday May 18th 2015, last year it was Sunday May 18th 2014...the nearest monday was Monday May 19th 2014...is this what you meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r6tecswb/4/)

**JS**

```
// this will get the number of days required to go forward to reach the same day
function forwardDay(begin, end) {
    var result = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        if (begin == end) return result;
        result++;
        if (begin == 6) {
            begin = 0;
        } else {
            begin++;
        }
    }
}

// this will get the number of days required to go forward to reach the same day
function backwardDay(begin, end) {
    var result = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        if (begin == end) return result;
        result++;
        if (end == 0) {
            end = 6;
        } else {
            end--;
        }
    }
}

// gets today 
var today = new Date();
// gets the day number of today 0-6
var thisYearDay = today.getDay();
// sets to last year
today.setYear(today.getFullYear() - 1);
// gets last years day 0-6
var lastYearDay = today.getDay()
// calculates the number of days it would be going backwards
var backward = backwardDay(lastYearDay, thisYearDay);
// gets the number of days it would be going forwards
var forward = forwardDay(lastYearDay, thisYearDay);

console.log(backward);
console.log(forward);

// figuring out which was was shorter
if (forward < backward) {
    today.setDate(today.getDate() + forward);
} else {
    today.setDate(today.getDate() - backward);
}
// DONE!
console.log(today);
```

Comment: The year is not good, you are in 114, not 2014! 

`Mon May 21 114 16:07:12 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Daylight Time)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `d.setMonth(date.getMonth() -- 12);` to get last year day and `var n = d.getDay();` to get day of week.

0 is Sunday, 1 is Monday

And next time use google first ;-)

Comment: He ask for Javascript, not VBScript!

Comment: @AlexisPaques My bad, I used method from another answer without checking. Edited.

Comment: Yep, took me 2 minutes on google with only a little previous experience with JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the `Date`

Here is an example :

```js
var a = new Date();
var day = a.getDay();
a.setYear(1900+a.getYear()-1);
a.setDate(a.getDay()- day -1 );
alert(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use one of JavaScript's built in functions, you can use the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object. Or if you want to calculate the day of the week on your own use [Zeller's Rule](https://web.archive.org/web/20171220131007/http://mathforum.org/dr.math/faq/faq.calendar.html).